# basic css li active only for some elements

Tags: html, css

I have two HTML lists I need one to select my "active" class and the other to ignore it.

Here is my css, I show an image "icon-plus.gif" and when user click the li the image change to "icon-minus.gif"

```
    li:before {content: url("icon-plus.gif");}
    li.active:before {content: url("icon-minus.gif");}
```

And then I have a two lists, and all the li show the image "icon-plus.gif" when I click it image change.

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul> 

<ul>
  <li>Bread</li>
  <li>Apples</li>
</ul>
```

both are showing the images!!! Really don't understand why, my idea it was having the class inside the li:

```
<ul>
  <li class"active">Coffee</li>
  <li class"active">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Code was downloaded from internet.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$("li").click(function () {
  // Remove active class from all li elements
  $("li").removeClass("active");
  // add the active class to your clicked on element
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript onclick() event and jquery's css manipulation may help you. Here is a useful link:

http://api.jquery.com/category/css/